# In what order should I call events in this logout sequence?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-authentication

Writing a kotlin social media app. I want to do 3 things within the logout sequence:

```
logoutbutton.setOnClickListener() {
            //1. db.logout()
            //2. finish()
            //3. go to login screen
        }
```

Does the order of events matter here? This is the order I am going with right now, but I don't know where the best place to put `finish()` would be.

Answer (score 1):

Call finish when you want the current activity to popped off the activity stack.  You typically do that when the user has indicated they no longer want to interact with it.  Other than that, the order of these things don't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

A trap that has caught me a few times is that finish() is actually asynchronous, so can give the illusion that instructions following it are "safe"... until they take a little longer and the activity gets torn down before they complete.
That can make for very difficult bugs to find.
I suggest for safety, call finish last.

I'm assuming db.logout may take some time to complete and/or may have to run on a background thread so some caution may be needed there. Fortunately Coroutines can help a lot .